# Cannot open MiKTeX, error “File is empty”. Cannot uninstall

Tags: latex, uninstall

I am using KDE neon.

After I installed MiKTeX, I updated everything from it, downloaded the "standard package" and then tried to install TeXStudio... a message appeared "installation failed". But TeXStudio is fine. I can run it.

I go to MiKTeX Console... and suddenly I am unable to enter, getting this message:
[image: MiKTeX Error Report]

Panic ensues. MiKTeX actually says in their documentation that entering the console is needed to first restore initial status to fully uninstall it.

But I can't.

Trying

```shell
sudo apt-get purge miktex
```

does nothing good.

It says that there is an empty file, the same thing as when you try to open the console:

> miktexsetup: File is empty.
> path="/home/MYUSERNAME/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/data/le/90a0591fc444a4d943d26e2f84799e00.fndb-5"

---

When executing

```shell
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq miktex
```

I get this:

```
(Reading database ... 174113 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing miktex (2.9.7300-bionic1) ...
miktexsetup: File is empty.
miktexsetup: Data: path="/home/MYUSERNAME/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/data/le/90a0591fc444a4d943d26e2f84799e00.fndb-5"
dpkg: error processing package miktex (--remove):
 installed miktex package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 miktex
```

What am I supposed to do?

MiKTeX Console still appears as if it is still a program.

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but personally I would recommend to use texlive instead of miktex on linux - much larger user base and better tested.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried to do it, but as MiKTeX was installed, errors and errors ensued.

Answer (score 2):

I more or less solved it.

I straight up deleted `~/.miktex` like this:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.miktex
```

and I reopened the console freely, and proceeded with the clean uninstall like here: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/1139034/1048142

Comment: That means some part of your *user* configuration  was borked.